# What does the wind speed have to be to knock over a glass of milk?

Tags: forces, speed

Say I want an average glass of milk knocked over by the wind. How much force would it require to knock it over?

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific as to what an average glass of milk is in your opinion.

Comment: Also what are the dimensions and shape of the glass?

Comment: -1. No research effort.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- 12 ounce glass of milk: mass of glass plus milk = 400 gram
- Glass is 15 cm tall and 7 cm diameter
- Center of mass is at 7 cm height
- Drag coefficient = 1.0 (this is approximately true over a fairly wide range of Reynolds numbers in the turbulent regime)
- Ignoring the fact that wind velocity will change with height - assume a glass on a small platform with uniform airflow

The force of the wind is given by

$$F_w = \frac12 \rho v^2 A C_D$$

And the force $F_t$ required to start tipping the glass is given by a balance of torques:

$$F_t ~h = F_g \frac{w}{2}$$

where $h$ is the mid point of the glass (apparent point where force acts), $w$ is the width of the base, and $F_g$ is force of gravity, $mg$.

When we set $F_w = F_t$, we find

$$\begin{align}
v &= \sqrt{\frac{2 F_w}{\rho A C_D}}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{mgw}{h\rho A C_D}}\end{align}$$

Substituting the values assumed above, I find v = 15 m/s, or approximately 54 km/h. This is very close to the experimental value that Joshua Lin quoted in his comment.

Calculation (in Python)

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> sqrt(0.3*9.8*0.07/(0.07*1.2*0.07*0.15*1))
15.275252316519467
>>> 15*3.6
54.0
```

Comment: +1, but I reckon 39 meters per second to be about 140 kilometers an hour. Also, copy and cite Joshua's comment - I'm still smiling imagining a nerd actually doing this and being willing to clean the mess up afterwards. I might have done this at a younger age!

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance - my bad. When I first calculated the conversion from m/s to km/h, I accidentally typed 2.6 instead of 3.6 for the conversion factor. When I copied my result, I read the wrong line (which I edited out of the calculation I just added...)

Comment: Are _all_ you guys bored?

Comment: @mmesser314 - procrastinating...